# JQuery - Separate tabs function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to get a seperate tabs function to work on my page, now I'm not experienced with JQuery or javascript. So I was looking to get some outside eyes on this JQuery code to see what the cause could be. Because currently all my content on the page is bundled together instead of being served individually by tabs.

```
<div>
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-3">Terms</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1">
  {{ dev.des }}
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2">
  {% render 'About' %}
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3">
  {{ terms.content }}
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
      var active, content, links = $(this).find('a');
      active = links.first().addClass('active');
      content = $(active.attr('href'));
      links.not(':first').each(function () {
        $($(this).attr('href')).hide();
      });
      $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
        active.removeClass('active');
        content.hide();
        active = $(this);
        content = $($(this).attr('href'));
        active.addClass('active');
        content.show();
        return false;
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Can you explain more what doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

set the class for tab content like below,

```
<div id="tab-1" class="content">
  {{ dev.des }}
</div>
```

CSS as,

```
.content {
   display : none;
}
.content.active {
   display : block;
}
```

Then on Jquery you can handle click for tab to change the class active by selecting id.